# Cassandra order by on combination of composite keys

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I originally wrote a table that tracks feeds that have been assigned to a user for review.

```
create table user_feed
{ 
     userid uuid,
     languageid uuid,
     topicid_uuid,
     dateinserted timeuuid,
     primary key (userid, languageid, topicid, dateinserted)
 };
```

I realized soon after I created this table that I wouldn't be able to sort this table (order by DESC) by dateinserted because for some weird reason, in Cassandra I can only order by the second (and last) column of a composite key table (as in, the table has to have 2 composite keys and order by can only happen on the second column of this key) so I changed my table to this:

```
create table user_feed
{ 
     userid uuid,
     languageid uuid,
     topicid_uuid,
     dateinserted timeuuid,
     primary key (userid, dateinserted)
 };
```

and now I was able to run a query to get the latest feeds for the user, using order by.

However, I have a new requirement that requires me to sort the feeds by a combination of (languageid + userid) or (topicid + userid) or (languageid + topicid + userid).

I had an idea to create three new tables and have the keys combined into one key column. For example, for userid + topic query, I would use:

```
create table user_feed_by_topic
{ 
     usertopicidkey text,
     dateinserted timeuuid,
     primary key (usertopicidkey, dateinserted)
 };
```

where usertopididkey = userid.toString() + topicid.toString().

Of course, this solution requires 4 separate inserts whenever I need to insert a new feed row since I have 4 rows, tracking identical data but partitioned differently to allow sorting.

My question is, is there a better way to do this? Is there any way to achieve what I want (query by a combination of columns and order by another column) or am I stuck with my 4 table design approach?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cassandra will order all rows based on the PKs clustering columns. In case your PK is `primary key (userid, languageid, topicid, dateinserted)` all rows will be sorted by languageid, topicid and dateinserted in ascending order. This implies that all rows will only be sorted within a specific language and topic by date. You'd have to use the date as the first clustering key column to change this behaviour.

Its common practice to denormalize your data across multiple tables to implement different ordering strategies.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Based on your last sentence, are you suggesting that having 4 tables in order to perform my paging by different criteria is the "recommended" or accepted approach?

Comment: Yes, its common practice to denormalize your data by use multiple tables for different sort ordering. Its also a good idea to use atomic batches for updating all those tables within a single batch.